# Value is not setted in React-redux-forms

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

Currently am passing the data to the Form component but it didn't reflected in my value field in Redux form . Actually i would like to do the ng-model(angular js) concept in redux forms . Here i attached my code ,

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import '../style.less'

class EditProfile extends Component {
 
 //here am getting the json value in 'info'
render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, errors, info } =      this.props;
   console.log("hello fname?---> "+info.fName);
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <div>
          <label 
          className="full-name-business-n" 
          htmlFor="fName">Full Name
          </label>
          
          <Field className="text-box-one"
          name="fName"
          component="input"
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={info.fName}
          />
          
        </div>
        
        <button 
         className="save-btn btn" 
         type="submit" 
         disabled={pristine || submitting}>SAVE
         </button>
         
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'editForm'
})(EditProfile)
```

1. In the console am getting the value
2. If i use `<input>` instead of `<Field>` mean's am getting the value .

so , where i made a mistake ? can someone clarify me please .
[Am beginner to redux-forms].

Comment: mee too searching for this. many are suggestion action creators

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the value and handling changes explicitly, but it's recommended that redux-form handle it for you.

All you need is to pass your `info` as `initialValues` prop into the form and the form can handle it from there.

So on your page you should have something like this:

```
<EditProfile
  initialValues={info}
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
/>
```

Then in your form this code should be enough

```
return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
     <div>
      <label 
        className="full-name-business-n" 
        htmlFor="fName">Full Name
      </label>

      <Field className="text-box-one"
        name="fName"
        component="input"
        type="text"
        // You don't need onChange unless you want to have a callback to do something with the value at the same time as it's persisting to redux store
        // onChange={this.handleChange}
        // value={info.fName}
      />

    </div>

    <button 
       className="save-btn btn" 
       type="submit" 
       disabled={pristine || submitting}>SAVE
     </button>

  </form>
);
```

You can see that your data is saving correctly if you open redux-dev-tools and see actions firing as you type.

By default you don't have access to your values as you type but you can achieve it by adding `formValueSelector`, but that's another story and most of the time I don't use it.